# What does swords icon mean after attack in Might and Magic Heroes VI?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

sometimes after an attack in combat in HoMM VI, I see not only damage dealt/units died counts, but also Swords icon with a number appear.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The 2 crossed swords icon means might damage. Certain abilities will reduce or increase the might damage of a stack of monsters.

My guess is you saw for example -1 X (crossed swords icon), meaning each creature in the stack will do 1 might damage less as long as the ability applies.

Answer (score 0):

The sword icons shows that the damage done was melee damage

Comment: hm, but isn't all the other damage done by melee troops (like sentine) melee aswell? besides, it usually only shows like "2" while total damage is like 200.

Comment: I could be wrong. It's been a while since I played M&M

Comment: Just re-read your response. You misunderstood. I didn't say that the icons **how much** damage was done, only that it was **melee** damage. Ranged get their own icons (dependant on what kind of ranged attack was used)

Comment: no, it's not like that. Now that I played more, there are more icons.

The normal icons just show a number and skull with number (how many units has died). Then sometimes I also get swords icon (with a +2 for example), a green cross icon, etc.. what do these mean?